# "a simple git branching model" - why rebase origin/my-new-feature?

Tags: git, github, git-workflow

I'm liking a lot "[a simple git branching model](https://gist.github.com/jbenet/ee6c9ac48068889b0912)". It keeps the master clean, history nicely formatted and informative, you can do code reviews on feature pushes, etc. But I'm confused with one aspect of it - why rebase on top of the pushed feature branch, what goal does it serve? If the branch is pushed for review, you will not have any commits to it so no reason to rebase. If the branch is used for collaboration, you would be probably better off just merging in other participant changes and rebasing on origin/master only. What I am missing?

P.S. Bonus question - if you use branches for pull requests, but you need to collaborate on the branches with other people, what is the best practice here? Is it common to have pull requests for branches?

Comment: "If the branch is used for collaboration, you would be probably better off just merging in other participant changes and rebasing on origin/master only" Why? There is no difference between rebasing onto master or onto a feature branch; the purpose of rebase is to prevent merge commits and thus keep history looking cleaner

Comment: @nevik-rehnel If you rebase, it changes your commits. So, if you rebase bach and forth between two origin branches, you are changing your history every time you rebase - EVEN if no activity on these branches. Because of this, if you had conflicts, you will have to resolve them every time you rebase, which does not happen if you rebase only on top of one branch.

Comment: Please refer to https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/git-branches#!merge and https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/rewriting-git-history#!rebase